# after unsubscribe, permission is still granted (PUSH NOTIFICATION WEB)

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am using the following code.

```
try {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    const subscription = await registration.pushManager.getSubscription();
    await subscription.unsubscribe();
} catch(error) {
    throw error;
}
```

Even After this code executes successfully, When I refresh the page and log `Notification.permission` , it's still granted. But It should be `default` . Am I missing something ?

If user grants the permission for the first time,  and then unsubscribes, `Notification.permission` never changes ?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, after calling unsubscribe, the result should be "denied" according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/permission) because it is an explicit user choice.
Can you check please if the permission is correctly removed in settings after your code is executed? On chrome go to settings -> privacy -> content settings -> scroll down to notifications or open chrome://settings/content/notifications

If the notification is still granted try to replace your code for test purposes with [Mozilla's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/unsubscribe) code and see if this works:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
  reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
    subscription.unsubscribe().then(function(successful) {
      console.log("unsubscribed");
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log("Something went wrong");
    })
  })        
});
```

The [spec](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#subscription-deactivation) (draft) says, that "a push subscription is removed when service worker registration is cleared."

Try to additionally unregister the serviceworker and see if this solves the problem:

```
registration.unregister().then(function(boolean) {
      // if boolean = true, unregister is successful
    });
```